# Время работы Math.Pow - const?

Tags: c#, сложность, time-complexity

Есть 2 функции, находящие n-ное число Фибоначчи. Первое находит через фор-лу Бине O(Log N), второе через метод итераций O(n).

```
static double SQRT5 = Math.Sqrt(5);
static double PHI = (SQRT5 + 1) / 2;
public static int Bine(int n)
{
    return (int)(Math.Pow(PHI, n) / SQRT5 + 0.5);
}
```

```
static long[] NumbersFibonacci = new long[35];
public static void Iteracii(int n)
{
NumbersFibonacci[0] = 0;
NumbersFibonacci[1] = 1;
for (int i = 1; i < n - 1; i++)
    {
        NumbersFibonacci[i + 1] = NumbersFibonacci[i] + NumbersFibonacci[i - 1];
    }
}
```

Но для нахождения 35 члена последовательности фор-ла Бине работает по времени хуже, чем метод итераций. При этом если вместо 35 написать достаточно большое число, например 1000000 (чисто в целях эксперимента), то время работы для фор-лы Бине не изменится, но для метода итераций возрастёт в несколько раз.

В связи с этим вопрос, сложность Math.Pow, который используется в фор-ле Бине (из-за которого такое время работы) на самом деле const, и если да, то как это доказать?

[image: Время работы алгоритмов]

Comment: вы все смешали в кучу. Ваш метод измерений сомнителен. Недостаточно 1 раз запустить метод, чтобы точно измерить воемя его работы. Воспользуйтесь готовой библиотекой BenchmarkDotNet для измерений. Мало того, ваш метод итераций кеширует результат в массиве. То есть вы можете при первом просчете посчитать массив до 35 элемента, при последующих запросах просто брать число из массива, что будет самым быстрым вариантом.

Comment: Надеюсь, вы эти измерения проводите в релизе, а не в дебаге?

Answer (score 2):

Очень просто доказать, что существует алгоритм работающий за константное время при определенных условиях, а значит в библиотечной функции скорее всего будет использован как минимум не худший алгоритм.

Существует алгоритм [быстрого возведения в степень](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC%D1%8B_%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B2_%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C) он требует `O(n)` операций умножения, где `n` - количество бит показателя.

Каждая операция умножения даже для не самого оптимального алгоритма требует `O(n*m)` элементарных операций, где `n` и `m` - количество бит в соответствующих числах.

Для каких нибудь бесконечных числовых типов константой тут и не пахнет, но в вашем случае используются типы с фиксированным количеством бит - `double` и `int`, а значит все эти `n` и `m` <strike>превращаются в тыкву</strike> – константы, следовательно и сам алгоритм возможно реализовать за `O(1)`.

#### Важное замечание

Ваш алгоритм способен работать только с очень небольшими аргументами, так вы еще и ограничиваете результат интом. Если программа действительно должна иметь возможность вычислять F<sub>1000000</sub> как в примере, имейте в виду, что результат будет занимать сотни тысяч бит и без неограниченных числовых типов вам не обойтись, а значит и константной сложности ждать не стоит.